# Rspec test for the existence of an action is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

i am working in Rspec of ROR.. 
I am trying to test my controllers using RSpec.i am having a Users controller with functions like new , tags, etc..

i created a file under spec/users_controller_spec.rb

and added the test cases as.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do
  integrate_views

  it "should use UsersController" do
    controller.should be_an_instance_of(UsersController)
  end


  describe "GET 'new'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'new'
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the title" do
      get 'new'
      response.should have_tag("title", "First app" )
    end
  end
end
```

which gets pass.

But when i add a test case for tags .. 
like

```
  describe "GET 'tags'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'tags'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
```

this results in an error as

F...

1)
'UsersController GET 'tags' should be successful' FAILED
expected success? to return true, got false

why it is coming like this ?? i am very new to ROR and cant find the reason of why i am getting this error..
How to make this pass . 
Also i tried the Url

http://localhost:3000/users/tags which is running for me .. But on testing using $spec spec/ i am getting the error ..

Comment: Can you show your route for this controller?

Comment: i searched in the routes.rb for the existence of 
 map.tags '/tags', :controller => 'users', :action => 'tags' But it was not there... Even if i added this and run the spec i m getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your test may be failing for any number of reasons. Does the route require an ID in the parameter hash? Is the controller action redirecting? Is the controller raising an error?

You'll need to look at the controller code /and/or `routes.rb` to discover the cause of the failure. Take note of `before` filters in the controller, which may not allow the action to be reachable at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add custom routes that are not within the default 7 routes. Assuming you have `resources :users` within your routes you will need to modify it. I'm also assuming that your tags route is unique to individual users.

```
resources :users do
  member do
    # creates /users/:user_id/tags
    get :tags
  end
end
```

And in your RSpec test you would call it like

```
describe '#tags' do
  user = create :user
  get :tags, user_id: user.id
end
```

If the route is not to be unique per user the other option is a collection route, something like:

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    # creates /users/tags
    get :tags
  end
end
```